# Подсчитать количество повторяющихся зрначений в многомерном массиве PHP

Tags: php

```
$users = array(
    array('login' => 'administrator', 'role' => 'admin'),
    array('login' => 'vasya', 'role' => 'user'),
    array('login' => 'petya', 'role' => 'admin'),
    array('login' => 'vova', 'role' => 'admin'),
    array('login' => 'klava', 'role' => 'user')
```

Как подсчитать количество admin`ов?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
$users = array(
    array('login' => 'administrator', 'role' => 'admin'),
    array('login' => 'vasya', 'role' => 'user'),
    array('login' => 'petya', 'role' => 'admin'),
    array('login' => 'vova', 'role' => 'admin'),
    array('login' => 'klava', 'role' => 'user')
);

$COUNT = 0;
foreach ($users as $value) {
    if (isset($value['role']) AND ($value['role'] == 'admin')) {
        $COUNT++;
    }
}
var_dump($COUNT);
```

Answer (score 1):

короткий по записи вариант:

```
$COUNT = array_count_values(array_column($users, 'role'))['admin'];
```

Использовались: [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php), [array_column](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php)

P.S. но вариант Manitikyl через foreach - быстрее работать будет, скорее всего.